# Could someone help me why is this happening?

Tags: rendering

When I open blender, and start rendering without changing anything, the time render starts about 2 min to get finished.

Like this[image]

[image]

but somehow, when I load the scene textures on viewport shading and render again,
the time render increases to 26 min

[image]
[image]

Idk what's going on.

To make it clear, i'm using an rx 6500 xt as GPU, and it has some limitations using PCI 3.0 or when it reaches vram limit.

Maybe it's just a hardware problem, but I don't think so, because sometimes this situation doesn't happen.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

It's an estimated time to finish the render, not the actual time it will take.  The only way to know how long it will take is to actually finish the frame render.

---

Your viewport takes resources from your hardware, if you make it display more complex things, there are less resources available for rendering.

To help with this, you could try locking the interface during renders:

[image: interface lock]

Or use command line rendering, which is even better.

[Command Line Rendering — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html)

```
blender -b "file.blend" -o "output.file" -a
```